# The rest of the owl: Knockout BindingHandlers with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, datatables, visual-studio-2017, knockout-3.0

I am trying in earnest to follow the accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862086/where-do-i-put-my-knockout-js-extensions-when-using-typescript-and-requirejs/15876149#15876149). I'm using Knockout, Typescript, MVC, VS2017 and node modules for most of my packages. The problem I'm having is that the binding does not get called but don't have any build errors.

> provide a definition file (say myBindings.d.ts)
>
> add the following code
>
> ```
>   interface KnockoutBindingHandlers {
>         csharpTypes: KnockoutBindingHandler;
>     }
> ```
>
> Reference this definition file in your extensions.ts file

---

Thus I created a `customKoBindings.d.ts` like this.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/knockout/index.d.ts" />

interface KnockoutBindingHandlers {
    dataTablesForEach: KnockoutBindingHandler;
}
```

---

I try to apply the binding in my cshtml. Do I need to pull in the ko.bindingHandler into my ViewModel in some way for it to be available for the view?

```
<table style="width: 100%" id="copyEmpTrainingSearchResultsTable" class="display" cellspacing="0">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th data-bind="sort: { arr: employees, prop: 'firstName' }">First Name</th>
                                                        <th data-bind="sort: { arr: employees, prop: 'lastName' }">Last Name</th>
                                                        <th data-bind="sort: { arr: employees, prop: 'jobTitle' }">Job Title</th>
                                                        <th data-bind="sort: { arr: employees, prop: 'primaryManager' }">Manager</th>
                                                        <th data-bind="sort: { arr: employees, prop: 'department' }">Department</th>
                                                        <th>Trainings</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: {data: trainingEmployeeSearchResults, dataTableOptions: {}}">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                                                        <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
                                                        <td data-bind="text: jobTitle"></td>
                                                        <td data-bind="text: primaryManager"></td>
                                                        <td data-bind="text: department"></td>
                                                        <td><button data-bind="click:$parent.seeTrainings"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

---

The answer says to add the binding to `extensions.ts`, so I created a new file. Binding code comes from [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31797/knockout-js-3-4-custom-binding-for-jquery-datatables-net). How would I reference the interface I created? What should be pointing to this file?

extensions.ts

```
import * as ko from "knockout"
import * as $ from "jquery";

export class KnockoutExtensions {
    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
            page: 0,
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                console.log("init for dataTablesForEach");
                var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
                ko.unwrap(options.data);
                if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
                    valueAccessor().data.subscribe(function (changes) {
                        var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
                        ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
                        table.destroy();
                    }, null, 'arrayChange');
                }
                var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node: Node) {
                    if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
                        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                    }
                });
                return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                console.log("update for dataTablesForEach");
                var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
                    key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
                ko.unwrap(options.data);
                var table;
                if (!options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
                    table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
                    table.destroy();
                }
                ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
                table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(options.dataTableOptions);
                if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
                    if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page == 0)
                        table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);
                    else
                        table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);
                }
                if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (options.data || options.length))
                    ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
                return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
            }
        }; 
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

In the [DefinitelyTyped documentation's test](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/knockout/test/templatingBehaviors.ts) they just do this, which I've now tried in the constructor of my viewModel but init and update still are not called:

> ```
>  (<any>ko.bindingHandlers).countInits = { init: function() { initCalls++ } };
> ```

---

**Update 2:**

I have not used requireJS in this project. Is it needed for linking the KnockoutBindingHandler in?

---

**Update 3:**

After reviewing this [article](https://magnealvheim.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/knockout-js-tutorials-in-typescript/), I've attempted to reference the above `customKoBindings.d.ts` with the node modules reference in my `tsconfig.json`. This did not it fix either.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/build/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "files": [
    "./Scripts/Common/customKoBindings.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

---

**Update Lost Count:**
It works!

added this to the top of `extensions.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./customKoBindings.d.ts" />
```

in my `main.ts` added this:

```
import { KnockoutExtensions} from "./Common/extensions"
const koExt = new KnockoutExtensions();
```

Comment: work around for the ultimate goal of keeping ko and datatable in sync https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822590/refresh-knockoutjs-data-in-datatables#31133320

Answer (score 4, accepted):

added this to the top of `extensions.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./customKoBindings.d.ts" />
```

in my `main.ts` added this:

```
import { KnockoutExtensions} from "./Common/extensions"
const koExt = new KnockoutExtensions();
```